Get a @Value field in a non-singleton Spring Boot-managed class
Prolusion
In a Spring Boot application, as best practices, I have a @RestController class and a @Service class that are obviously a singleton. Also, the Controller and the Service can access a @Value instance field read from a .properties file.
The flow I want to create is: the Controller calls a Service method, the Service has to create a new instance of an Entity, we can easily agree that the Entity mustn't be a singleton.
@RestController
public class Controller{
  @Value("${var}")
  private String var;

  @Autowired
  private Service service;

  @PostMapping("/endpoint")
  public void endpoint(){
    // here, I can read this.var

    service.methodService();
  }
}

@Service
public class Service{
  @Value("${var}")
  private String var;

  public void methodService(){
    // here, i can read this.var, too

    Entity entity = new Entity();
  }
}

public class Entity{
  @Value("${var}")
  private String var;

  public Entity(){
    // here, var will surely be null
  }
}

Problem
Can I read the var instance field in Entity, in a way that goes with the constraints I described? Or is this design idea wrong upstream?
Note that the following isn't accepted because it wouldn't meet the constraints (Entity would a singleton):
@Component
public class Entity{
  ...
}

@Service
public class Service{
  @Autowired
  private Entity entity;
  ...
}

It also goes without saying that I wouldn't like to have:
public class Entity{
  private String var;

  public Entity(String var){
    this.var = var;
  }
}

Because I would like to handle the problem with Spring Boot dependency management.
